# Delete Windows Update Residuals using Disk Cleanup via Powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I delete/cleanup all the folders under "Clean System Files" option in disk cleanup via powershell? The code below wasn't able to achieve what I wanted to.

```
(Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\cleanmgr.exe" -ArgumentList "/sagerun:1" -Wait -PassThru)
```

Thank you,

Comment: did you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852786/automate-process-of-disk-cleanup-cleanmgr-exe-without-user-intervention

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the autoclean option?

```
cleanmgr.exe /AUTOCLEAN
```

It will clean below folders:
C:$Windows.~BT*
C:$Windows.~LS*
C:$Windows.~WS*
C:\ESD\Download*
C:\ESD\Windows*
C:$WINDOWS.~Q*
C:$INPLACE.~TR*
C:\Windows.old*
C:\Windows\Panther

It will also write 2 log files as following:

> C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\setupcln\setupact.log
> C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\setupcln\setuperr.log

Answer (score 0):

you can delete them one by one by starting the cmd in admin mode.
below is an example to delete the **$windows.~BT** folder

```
takeown /F C:\$Windows.~BT\* /R /A 
icacls C:\$Windows.~BT\*.* /T /grant administrators:F 
rmdir /S /Q C:\$Windows.~BT\
```